# How did lambda expressions get their name?

Tags: lambda

I may be showing my ignorance here, but why are lambda expressions called lambda expressions. I understand how to use them, but I'm curious if there is any significance to the term "lambda".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

Comment: I disagree with closing of this question; this is easy to understand meaningful and relevant inquiry. Etymology facilitates insight into (involved) concepts encapsulated within (single) words. Words are empty pointers. Context gives them substance. Knowing where words come from - how they came to be, what they pointed to in the past, in other domains - helps developing (a robust) comprehension. More so when a specter as abstruse and seemingly solitarily eccentric as `lambda` appears. Our mind is associative; reject that as your choice and let those who are willing to work with it proceed.

Comment: i edited the question - and want it to be reopened. I don't get the exact correlation between lambda and lambda-expressions in java8 either. We discussed this in class - but couldn't get the destinct connection. 

Refering to the Lambda-Calculus is not an adequate answer. What does this relation mean?

Comment: For the record, I do not approve the edit, this question was not intended to be language specific and I thought the approved answer was adequate. But others approved it so.. Yay stackoverflow.

Comment: @ConditionRacer Think about this in a wikipedia context. The question was closed because it was to unspecific. I read alot about lambda-expressions today - and i could answer it  better. Also there are no similar questions. Java is just an example. its your question, feel free to edit it. My sole intention was to give someone googling the same question a better understanding.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The term derived from mathematical key word only.

Wiki info : [Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)

check this : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lambda+expression

Comment: this is not an answer, its a reference.

Answer (score 8):

Because they come from Church's [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).